# Certificate chain - is my Intermediate correct

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate

One thing I could not find. I've just received a Comodo ssl certificate (.crt file and a key) from a client to install on the webserver. I did not receive an Intermediate though. The certificate CN is:

```
Extended Validation Secure Server CA
```

and i did find this Intermediate on Comodo website:

```
https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/931/91/intermediate-2-comodo-ev-secure-server-ca
```

How can I check whether this particular certificate is validated by this Intermediate?

I was trying

```
openssl verify -verbose -purpose sslserver -CAfile comodoextendedvalidationsecureserverca.crt my_certificate.crt
```

but got this error:

```
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Which I would expect if the validation fails. But surprisingly I got similar error (`error 2 at 1 depth lookup:unable to get issuer certificate`) while trying this command on a certificate/Intermediate pair I'm sure is correct.

I want to make sure, I'm out of options of finding a proper Intermediate, before i start nagging my client.

Comment: The intermediate CA should be passed to `openssl verify` command after the `-untrusted` option.

Answer (score 0):

As Patrick suggested:

```
openssl verify -purpose sslserver -untrusted <Intermediate_file.crt> <cerificate_file.crt>
```

Is a good way to go. Thanks